# Proper way to clean something when closing Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that need to wirte something in localStorage and clean (or set a special value) when user close the browser.
[This link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30885) showing that there is no way to detect when the browser is closed.
So any suggestion?

Comment: I think we need a bit more information on the data itself, is the data sensitive? If so, maybe this is an encryption problem.

Comment: no, its not, just some number like timstamp when user first open the browser.

Comment: The user closing the browser is an event you may miss (in case of a crash, for example).  Why would you not be able to write a startup timestamp at the startup time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a persistent [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html), use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage` to save variables.

If you're using an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html), then you need to maintain some kind of session identifier, and prefix your value or key with this identifier. This identifier can be stored in `localStorage` and must be refreshed during the [`chrome.runtime.onStartup`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onStartup) and [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onInstalled) events.

Comment: Event pages exit with `runtime.onSuspend` (or try to).